# Passing a javascript variable to a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, constructor, javascript-objects

I have a mapping application that lists different map layers in a menu, with each layer having a particular class name.

This class name is used when the user clicks on the name so that the layer can be either added to or removed from the map, and also the layer be added / removed from a map key.

This is working ok, but I am struggling with including a small cross next to each layer name so the user can remove them from the map key.

My code is below - I try to include an onclick function which takes the layer id and tries to use this in a function but I get an error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .icon[object
>   Object]

As my variable is now an object do I need to specify the `lid` in a different way?

The html is here which shows the list option for a layer that uses the class id:

```
<li class='last layerlist' id='layer63'><a href='#'><i class="fa fa-circle fa-lg iconlayer63"></i><span> Flood Zone 2</span></a></li>
```

The Javascript below shows what happens when the user clicks on the list, it takes the id, and then uses this to get the layer name (which is the same as the id) to either hide or show the layer depending on if it is visible:

```
//Change layer visibility and add / remove from map key
$(".layerlist").click(function() {
    var lid = $(this).attr('id');
    map.getLayers().forEach(function(layer) {
        if (layer.get('name') == lid) {
            var visibility = layer.getVisible();
            if (visibility == false) {
                layer.setVisible(true);
                $(".icon" + lid).removeClass("fa-circle").addClass("fa-check-circle");
                $("#map-content").append("<p id='" + lid + "key'><a href='#'><i class='fa fa-times-circle' onclick='removeLayer(" + lid + ");'></i></a><img src='img/legend/" + lid + ".png' alt='Layer image'/> " + layer.get('label') + "</p>");
            }
            if (visibility == true) {
                layer.setVisible(false);
                $(".icon" + lid).removeClass("fa-check-circle").addClass("fa-circle");
                $("#" + lid + "key").remove();
            }
        }
    });
});

//Remove selected layer from map key
function removeLayer(lid) {
    lid.setVisible(false);
    $(".icon" + lid).removeClass("fa-check-circle").addClass("fa-circle");
    $("#" + lid + "key").remove();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of HTML code, please ?

Comment: lid is an object which is getting coerced to a string hence the [object Object], can you tell more about lid?

Comment: remove layer is expecting a `layer` object and you are passing it a string - that obviously won't work :)

Comment: Part of `removeLayer` is expecting the argument `lid` to be an object: `lid.setVisible(false);` Almost everything else is using it as a string, e.g.: `$(".icon" + lid)...` What is that `setVisible` line supposed to do?

Comment: Yes the lid.setVisible(false) is supposed to remove the map layer from the map. I tried your suggestion T.J with adding the quotes and it works, but this part doesn't - presumably because this needs the object, and the other two lines need it as a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your `onclick` attribute:

```
"... onclick='removeLayer(" + lid + ");' ..."
```

What the browser will see, if `lid` is `"foo"`, will be:

```
... onclick='removeLayer(foo);' ...
```

Note that that means `removeLayer` will be called expecting a variable called `foo`, not the **string** `"foo"`.

Browsers create globals for all elements that have an `id`; the global refers to the element object. So `foo` will refer to the element, not its `id`.

You wanted quotes:

```
"... onclick='removeLayer(\"" + lid + "\");' ..."
```

so the browser sees

```
... onclick='removeLayer("foo");' ...
```

Having said that, one part of `removeLayer` seems to expect an object:

```
lid.setVisible(false);
```

You'd have to tell us more about that for us to be able to fully help you.

---

**But**, rather than fix it by adding quotes, I would stop using `onxyz` attributes entirely. Instead, use modern event handling.

Remove the `onclick` attribute, and instead:

```
$(document.body).on("click", "selector-for-all-lids", function() {
    // We need to know more to help with this line: lid.setVisible(false);
    var lid = this.id;
    $(".icon" + lid).removeClass("fa-check-circle").addClass("fa-circle");
    $("#" + lid + "key").remove();
});
```

Comment: As I need both an object (to set the layer visibility of my layer) and a string (to remove the entry from my key) perhaps I need to parse two separate variables in my onclick function, so I can use both an object and a string?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I included two separate variables to cater for both the object and string.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".icon" + lid)
```

If you lid is an object this will be converted to ".icon[Object object]"

So yes you have to change this. Just check what this line return and change your code to get along with it :

```
 var lid = $(this).attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

If "lid" is an object than you can't write something like this `$(".icon" + lid)`. Instead, you should use something like `$(".icon" + lid.paramName)`